# Merge multiple strings with identical content but overlapping HTML tags in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

The title itself does not feel like a clear question so I'll provide an example instead:

I have an example string:

```
Created and managed websites for clients to communicate securely
```

and there are many "versions" of it. What that means is a word or a phrase in a "version" of the string will be enclosed in HTML div tags, i.e. `<div style="font-size: 0.1000000">foo bar</div>`. (These tags are arbitrary, the numbers given to the font-size attribute correspond to scores which will later be used as other CSS features that are irrelevant now.) Here are 4 versions of the string:

```
Created and <div style="font-size: 1">managed</div> websites for clients to communicate securely
Created and <div style="font-size: 2">managed websites</div> for clients to communicate securely
Created and managed websites for clients to <div style="font-size: 3">communicate</div> securely
<div style="font-size: 4">Created</div> and managed websites for clients to communicate securely
```

I want to merge all these versions into this:

`<div style="font-size: 4">Created</div> and <div style="font-size: 2"><div style="font-size: 1">managed</div> websites</div> for clients to <div style="font-size: 3">communicate</div> securely`

As we see here, there are overlapping tags (in the tags with `font-size: 2` and `font-size: 1`). The number of versions of a string could range anywhere between 1 to 50, so there may be multiple overlaps.

Here is what I have so far using regexes:

```py
import re

div_str = "<div style=.*</div>"  # the div tags
div_text_str = "(?<=(>)).*(?=(</div>))"  # the content inside the div tags

# compile the regexes
div_regex = re.compile(div_str)
div_text_regex = re.compile(div_text_str)

def merge_strings(str1, str2):

    # grab the div tag off the first version
    div = div_regex.search(str1).group()
    # grab the contents of that div tag
    div_text = div_text_regex.search(div).group()

    # find the div content in the second version, then substitute
    # with the div tag
    return re.sub(div_text, div, str2)
```

I am running this function in a loop and attempting to merge 2 strings at a time until I get the final output. The problem I am facing is that the overlapping tags don't work with this function since the regex pattern won't match it. Also, replacing multiple div tags at once fails.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Replacing regexes with BeautifulSoup to make the parsing easier, I sorted these versions by the length of the text between the div tags to not run into any issues with finding substrings.

Using the same sample:

```
Created and <div style="font-size: 1">managed</div> websites for clients to communicate securely
Created and <div style="font-size: 2">managed websites</div> for clients to communicate securely
Created and managed websites for clients to <div style="font-size: 3">communicate</div> securely
<div style="font-size: 4">Created</div> and managed websites for clients to communicate securely
```

the lines are represented in a list which is then sorted by the length of the text between their corresponding div tags using BeautifulSoup. Here is the code:

```py
def __merge_strings(final_str, version):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(final_str, "html.parser")

    for fixed_div in soup.find_all("div"):
        if not fixed_div.text == version.text:
            return final_str.replace(
                version.text, unicode(version)
            )

    return final_str

found_terms = (
    (i, BeautifulSoup(i, "html.parser").find("div"))
    for i in found_terms
)  # list of pairs of the version and its div text
found_terms = sorted(
    found_terms, key=lambda x: len(x[-1].text), reverse=True
)  # sort on the length of the div text to avoid issues with substrings

current_div = found_terms[0][0]  # version with the largest div text
for i in xrange(1, len(found_terms)):
    current_div = __merge_strings(current_div, found_terms[i][-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a proper answer.

I would mention that parsing HTML with regex usually makes life unnecessarily difficult. Better to use a parser such as BeautifulSoup, lxml, scrapy, etc.

It's easy to recover the texts from each of the lines that you have offered as examples. I assume that each is part of a bigger construction; I have therefore enclosed each within a `div`.

Here I use BeautifulSoup to get the text from each of your lines.

```
>>> for line in open('temp.htm').readlines():
...     line = line.strip()
...     print(line)
...     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')
...     soup.find('div').text
...     
<div>Created and <div style="font-size: 1">managed</div> websites for clients to communicate securely</div>
'Created and managed websites for clients to communicate securely'
<div>Created and <div style="font-size: 2">managed websites</div> for clients to communicate securely</div>
'Created and managed websites for clients to communicate securely'
<div>Created and managed websites for clients to <div style="font-size: 3">communicate</div> securely</div>
'Created and managed websites for clients to communicate securely'
<div><div style="font-size: 4">Created</div> and managed websites for clients to communicate securely</div>
'Created and managed websites for clients to communicate securely'
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand how, in general, you would map input lines to output HTML.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is being used in the project to parse the input HTML! The text you extracted from the lines already exist - they are being used in a different analysis which returns these different versions. Ultimately, the project parses an HTML file -> does analysis that generates these versions -> replaces original HTML contents with all these versions merged like in my example.